# I am looking for te extend my abbrv.bst file to contain some other informations

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Hope you doing well,
I want to extend my style abbrv.bst that showd ISBN numbers stated and linked to worldcat.org, titles of articles and books with DOI linked accordingly to doi.org, and links to the pdf les

Comment: The `abbrvnat` bib style may be of interest to you. Unlike `abbrv`, `abbrvnat` recognizes fields called `isbn`, `doi`, and `url`.

Comment: Since `abbrv.bst` is a BibTeX style and `biblatex` is completely incompatible with classical BibTeX and its styles, I removed the `biblatex` tag and replaced it with BibTeX. If you are specifically looking for a `biblatex` solution, please mention that in your question explicitly.